# Entity with many-to-many relationship creation fails after upgrading to RC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, poco

I've got a project with 3 simple tables, a couple of POCO classes, and a DBContext created with code, no edml file. The following code setup used to work with the beta of Entity Framework code-first, I've edited the DbContext code since the ModelBuilder changed from the beta to RC

Tables (simple tables many-to-many table has fields declared as foreign keys with cascade deletion):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookings](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bookings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Units](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Beds] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Units] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UnitBookings](
    [UnitId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BookingId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

POCOS:

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Beds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
```

DB Context

```
public class BookingDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Bookings)
            .WithMany(b => b.Units)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("BookingId").MapRightKey("UnitId").ToTable("UnitBookings"));
    }
}
```

Creating a Booking (the bookingCarrrier is a helper class delivered by frontend layer)

```
public static bool CreateBooking(BookingCarrier carrier, out string statusMsg)
{
    using (var db = new BookingDB())
    {
        var validator = new BookingValidator(2, 3);
        Booking booking = CreateBooking(carrier, db);
        if (validator.Validate(booking.AccountId, booking, -1, out statusMsg)
        {
            db.Bookings.Add(booking);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private static CreateBooking(BookingCarrier carrier, BookingDB db)
{
    var units = new List<Unit>();
    if (carrier.SelectedUnit == 0)
        units.AddRange(db.Units.ToList());
    else
        units.Add(db.Units.Find(carrier.SelectedUnit));
    return new Booking
        {
            AccountId = carrier.AccountId,
            EndDate = carrier.EndDate,
            StartDate = carrier.StartDate,
            Units = units
        };
}
```

When executing this code, EF throws a SqlException with the following message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_UnitBookings_Units". The conflict
>   occurred in database "grashult.dk",
>   table "dbo.Units", column 'ID'.

Which wasn't the case in the beta.

I know this is a fairly simplistic setup, but since this a hobby project, and I'm trying it out to see how simple a thing like this can be done.

Are anybody aware of changes that causes this behaviour? Is something like this still possible with EF 4.1, or do I have to whip out the data model designer?

Regards
Jesper Hauge

Comment: This should work. Use SQL profiler and check that EF is inserting valid unit ids into junction table.

Comment: I haven't got a SQL Profiler handy, but I've checked the ID properties on the Units in the list during debuggin, and they are exactly what they should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must swap your key mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Bookings)
            .WithMany(b => b.Units)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UnitId")
                       .MapRightKey("BookingId")
                       .ToTable("UnitBookings"));
```

I just tested it and the problem was that `Booking.Id` was stored in `UnitId` and `UnitId` in `Booking.Id`.